# Unit test a dynamic instance throws exception if not abstracted from a specific base in c#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, reflection, mocking

I have a class similar to the following

```
class ObjectCaller
{
    public void Process (String NameSpace) {

        Type t = Type.GetType(NameSpace + ".Main");
        if (t != null)
        {
            if (t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Window)))
            {
                Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            }
            else {
                throw new NotAbstractedException();
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new MainNotFoundException();
        }

    }
}
```

A namespece is passed to the `Render()` Method of the class and the passed namespace should have a class `.Main` and also the class should be abstracted from `Window` class. Which is working fine. But I am unable to do unit test so that if the class `Main` exists but it is not an abstract class of `Window`, it should throw an exception.

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(NotAbstractedException))]
    public void MainNotAbstractedTest() {

        ObjectCaller oc = new ObjectCaller();
        oc.Process("name.space.of.class");
    }
```

I have tried using **MOQ** to MOCK `System.Type` classes `IsSubClassOf` method and with searching have found that its not possible to MOCK static classes. And also I don't want to change `ObjectCaller` just for the purpose of UnitTesting, Is there any possible way to make the method Process throw the exception `NotAbstractedException` without changing the class i am loading dynamically or no changing `ObjectCaller` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just test it by passing it a namespace which contains a class called `Main` which isn't derived from `Window`.

Now you may find that tricky because if `Type.GetType(string)` is passed a value which is a non-assembly-qualified name, it will only look in `mscorlib` and the calling assembly - which in your case is the *production* code assembly. So your options are:

- If you only ever want to use types from that assembly, then keep your current call to `Type.GetType`, but add a unit test to ensure that you don't have any classes called `Main` which *aren't* derived from `Window`. At that point, you can get rid of the `IsSubclass` test
- Otherwise, allow the caller to pass in an assembly or assembly name - allowing you to put appropriate classes in your unit test assembly instead.